# Answer options to a question are pulled up incorrectly

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Below is a simplified version of my multiple choice test.
Say, we have got five questions and four answer options to each question.

Аll five questions are answered one after another/one at a time, that is one question with the corresponding answer choices is shown on a separate screen. Example below.
![Text]([image])

On the last screen I want to make a summary of the completed work and render all questions and answers on one screen.

The problem may seem stupid, but I have puzzled my head over it for some time, can’t solve it.

The problem is that on the last screen the questions themselves are rendered correctly, but the answer choices to them not: only the 4th answer choice is repeatedly displayed in each of the four cells, instead of different answer choices as in the database `QuestionManager`. Example below. (The 2nd line displays “Option2” instead of the number from the database, because `option2.text = answer.text` in `CustomFinalCell` is commented out for the sake of experiment.) How to make it show different answer choices as in the database?

![Text]([image])

```
class QuestionManager {
  enum LevelType: String {
    case beginners = "Beginners"
    case middle = "Middle"
    case advanced = "Advanced"
  }
  
  // MARK: - Properties
  
  private (set) var questions: [Question] = []
  private (set) var answers: [Answer] = []
  private (set) var currentQuestion: Question?
  private (set) var questionNumber: Int = 0
  public var levelType: LevelType = .beginners
  
  // MARK: - Constants
  
  public let defaultQuestions: [LevelType: [Question]] = [
    .advanced: [
      Question(text: "What is 2 / 2?", answers: [
        Answer(text: "1", correct: true),
        Answer(text: "2", correct: false),
        Answer(text: "4", correct: false),
        Answer(text: "7", correct: false)
      ], explanation: "The correct answer will be is as it is a Singular form."),
      Question(text: "What is 10 / 2?", answers: [
        Answer(text: "1", correct: false),
        Answer(text: "12", correct: false),
        Answer(text: "4", correct: false),
        Answer(text: "5", correct: true)
      ], explanation: "The correct answer will be is as it is a Singular form."),
      Question(text: "What is 27 / 3?", answers: [
        Answer(text: "10", correct: false),
        Answer(text: "9", correct: true),
        Answer(text: "11", correct: false),
        Answer(text: "12", correct: false)
      ], explanation: "The correct answer will be is as it is a Singular form."),
      Question(text: "What is 32 / 4?", answers: [
        Answer(text: "7", correct: false),
        Answer(text: "8", correct: true),
        Answer(text: "9", correct: false),
        Answer(text: "10", correct: false)
      ], explanation: "The correct answer will be is as it is a Singular form."),
      Question(text: "What is 100 / 2?", answers: [
        Answer(text: "100", correct: false),
        Answer(text: "30", correct: false),
        Answer(text: "40", correct: false),
        Answer(text: "50", correct: true)
      ], explanation: "The correct answer will be is as it is a Singular form.")
    ]
  ]
}
```

```
class CustomFinalCell: UITableViewCell {
  
  private var questionManager: QuestionManager!
    
  @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var option1: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var option2: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var option3: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var option4: UILabel!
  
  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
  }
  
  // MARK: - Public methods
  
  public func configure(with question: Question, with answers: [Answer]) {
      questionLabel.text = question.text
//        option1 = viewWithTag(1) as? UILabel
//        option2 = viewWithTag(2) as? UILabel
//        option3 = viewWithTag(3) as? UILabel
//        option4 = viewWithTag(4) as? UILabel

    for answer in answers {
      option1.text = answer.text
//      option2.text = answer.text
      option3.text = answer.text
      option4.text = answer.text
    }
   }
  }
```

```
class ResultViewController: UIViewController {
  
  //   MARK: - Properties
  
  private var questionManager: QuestionManager!
  private var questions: [Question] = []
  private var answers: [Answer] = []
  
  // MARK: - Create
  
  static func create(with questionManager: QuestionManager) -> ResultViewController {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "result") as! ResultViewController
    vc.questionManager = questionManager
    return vc
  }
  
  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
  
  // MARK: - Private methods
  
  
  private func configureTableView() {
    
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomFinalCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customFinalCell")
    //    tableView.backgroundColor = .gray
    //    self.tableView.reloadData()
    print("Hello, world!")
  }

  private func configureQuestionView() {
    for question in questions {
      let questionView = QuestionView(question: question)
      tableView.addSubview(questionView)
    }
  }
  
  // MARK: - Lifecycle
  
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .cyan
    navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
    configureTableView()
  }
}

// MARK: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource

extension ResultViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
  
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    questionManager.questions.count
  }
  
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customFinalCell", for: indexPath) as? CustomFinalCell else {
      return UITableViewCell()
    }
        
    let question = questionManager.questions[indexPath.row]

    answers = question.answers
  
    cell.configure(with: question, with: answers)
        
    return cell
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop in your `CustomFinalCell` class is incorrect.  Try replacing this part of your code

```
for answer in answers {
    option1.text = answer.text
//    option2.text = answer.text
    option3.text = answer.text
    option4.text = answer.text
}
```

with this

```
option1.text = question.answers[0].text
option2.text = question.answers[1].text
option3.text = question.answers[2].text
option4.text = question.answers[3].text
```

and your problem should be fixed.

The reason the original was incorrect is that using a loop here iterates over each of the 4 answer choices to the question, then, on the final iteration, assigns all 4 rows to the final answer in the array.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! It really works! It seems to be a simple solution, but I wouldn't figure this out on my own. Now I will try to make the next step - add randomness to answers separately on each screen and the preservation of the same random subsequence of answer choices in the summary on the final screen.